Exclude/Include some url paths to open the apps - Deep Linking
I have implemented deep link in my manifest which is working fine with all the URLs.
I have a different domain and 2 below URLs from that I need to include and exclude URLs to redirect to the app
exclude:
https://www.example.com/talks/view_all.aspx

include:
https://www.example.com/talks/item1-chat/
https://www.example.com/talks/item2-chat/

Manifest intent filter
 <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

       <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

       <data android:scheme="https" />
       <data android:host="www.example.com" />
       <data android:pathPattern="/talks/..*" />
  </intent-filter>

As of now, all the URLs redirect to the application. I want to restrict some of the URLs as I mentioned above.
Thank you!

What you want is currently not possible on Android, unfortunately. You will have to be specific on your allowed Paths, in order to avoid unwanted paths to flow into the App. In your example, defining your intent filter as:

path: https://www.example.com/talks/item.*

Would do the job.
This can get complicated quite quikcly, and hard to manage in the long term. You can use the Deep Links page Google Play Console to patch your deep links without having to do a full app release.
